# Summarise all values for a particular key in JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following json stored in a column in my database. I'm using this JSON to populate a table in one of my views which works great. What I'm now trying to do is **calculate a sum** of all of the values for a particular key --> sum of every ("`ownership_percentage`") for each "`shareholder`".

```
{
   "captable":{
      "id":28,
      "version":1,
      "name":"CapTable",
      "company_id":22,
      "created_at":"2018-10-31T18:56:03.965Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-31T18:57:30.626Z",
      "total_stocks_in_company":"400.0"
   },
   "event":{
      "status_locked":null,
      "id":51,
      "price_per_share":"1000.0",
      "total_company_stocks_after_event":"400.0",
      "name":"2nd event ",
      "date":"2018-10-31",
      "currency":"SEK",
      "valuation":"400000.0",
      "created_at":"2018-10-31T18:57:17.282Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-31T18:57:30.676Z",
      "captable_id":28,
      "company_id":22,
      "snapshot":"{\"captable\":{\"id\":28,\"total_stocks_in_company\":\"400.0\",\"version\":1,\"name\":\"CapTable\",\"company_id\":22,\"created_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:56:03.965Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:30.626Z\"},\"event\":{\"status_locked\":null,\"id\":51,\"price_per_share\":\"1000.0\",\"total_company_stocks_after_event\":\"400.0\",\"name\":\"2nd event \",\"date\":\"2018-10-31\",\"currency\":\"SEK\",\"valuation\":\"400000.0\",\"created_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:17.282Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:30.665Z\",\"captable_id\":28,\"company_id\":22,\"snapshot\":null},\"shareholders\":[{\"id\":52,\"shareholder\":\"Peter\",\"name\":\"Peter\",\"number_of_stocks\":\"100.0\",\"company_id\":22,\"created_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:55:42.730Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:30.637Z\",\"ownership_percentage\":\"0.25\",\"email\":\"\",\"telephone\":\"\"},{\"id\":53,\"shareholder\":\"Jane\",\"name\":\"Jane\",\"number_of_stocks\":\"100.0\",\"company_id\":22,\"created_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:55:49.490Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:30.644Z\",\"ownership_percentage\":\"0.25\",\"email\":\"\",\"telephone\":\"\"},{\"id\":54,\"shareholder\":\"Sally\",\"name\":\"Sally \",\"number_of_stocks\":\"200.0\",\"company_id\":22,\"created_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:55:56.192Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-31T18:57:30.651Z\",\"ownership_percentage\":\"0.5\",\"email\":\"\",\"telephone\":\"\"}]}"
   },
   "shareholders":[
      {
         "id":52,
         "shareholder":"Peter",
         "name":"Peter",
         "number_of_stocks":"50.0",
         "company_id":22,
         "created_at":"2018-10-31T18:55:42.730Z",
         "updated_at":"2018-10-31T18:58:31.406Z",
         "ownership_percentage":"0.125",
         "email":"",
         "telephone":""
      },
      {
         "id":53,
         "shareholder":"Jane",
         "name":"Jane",
         "number_of_stocks":"150.0",
         "company_id":22,
         "created_at":"2018-10-31T18:55:49.490Z",
         "updated_at":"2018-10-31T18:58:31.410Z",
         "ownership_percentage":"0.375",
         "email":"",
         "telephone":""
      },
      {
         "id":54,
         "shareholder":"Sally",
         "name":"Sally ",
         "number_of_stocks":"200.0",
         "company_id":22,
         "created_at":"2018-10-31T18:55:56.192Z",
         "updated_at":"2018-10-31T18:57:30.651Z",
         "ownership_percentage":"0.5",
         "email":"",
         "telephone":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Just to add another layer - the ownership_percentage is a string, so that need to be converted into either a decimal/float before performing the sum so that one liner is getting a bit long :)

What I'd like to achieve is the following (pseudocode) but I'm having trouble finding a one liner that works well for me. Would love a push in the right direction here!

```
<td> <%= snapshot_json["shareholders"]["ownership_percentage"].to_f.sum %> </td>
```

*Note: The ownership_percentage in this example should summarise up to 1.0 (i.e. 100%).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass a block to [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) on your `shareholders` array

```
snapshot_json["shareholders"].sum { |x| x["ownership_percentage"].to_f }
```

Comment: Had to change it to this (but then it works great!) 

`snapshot_json["shareholders"].sum { |x| x["ownership_percentage"].to_f }`

Thank you!

Comment: Not 100% sure on what it does - will search for that syntax and read up in the Ruby docs. Edit: saw your update now, will read up on that thanks again!